# XElement.element() returns null sometimes

Tags: c#, xml, null, xml-namespaces

I'm loading an XML file, getting the values of some nodes and then setting those values into an object.

The problem is that although I can get into the each node, I can't get its value: it just returns null.  Searching in Google and SO I found several threads saying that usually it is a problem of namespaces.  So I set up a namespace on the XML file and in my code to work with it.  This is now when things get funny:

- If all the nodes but the last one are prefixed (in my code) with the namespace, all of them gets set except that particular one which gives an ArgumentNullException (`tabla` does not accept nulls on some properties).  This seems to be expected behavior.
- if I correct that last line and set up the namespace (as it should be), then the exception gets raised at the FIRST node.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://daniel.ponticelli.com/ns/dataExport">
  <PollInstance>
    <Poll_Instance_id>1</Poll_Instance_id>
    <POLL_description>Mes 1</POLL_description>
    <dt_start>01/09/2012 12:00:00 a.m.</dt_start>
    <dt_end>30/09/2012 12:00:00 a.m.</dt_end>
    <POLL_status>0</POLL_status>
    <dt_created>03/09/2012 09:50:36 a.m.</dt_created>
    <dt_updated>03/09/2012 09:50:36 a.m.</dt_updated>
    <id_original_clone>0</id_original_clone>
    <target_locs>0</target_locs>
    <id_poll>1</id_poll>
  </PollInstance>
</root>
```

This is the "wrong" code that has the last element without namespace:

```
XElement instancia = xml.Descendants().First();
XNamespace ra = "http://daniel.ponticelli.com/ns/dataExport";

tabla.Poll_Instance_id = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "Poll_Instance_id");
tabla.POLL_description = (string)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_description");
tabla.dt_start = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_start"));
tabla.dt_end = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_end"));
tabla.POLL_status = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_status");
tabla.dt_created = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_created"));
tabla.dt_updated = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_updated"));
tabla.id_original_clone = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "id_original_clone");
tabla.target_locs = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "target_locs");
tabla.id_poll = (int)instancia.Element("id_poll");
```

The previous code gives the exception on the last line.

Now this is the "correct" code that has all the elements prefixed with the namespace:

```
XElement instancia = xml.Descendants().First();
XNamespace ra = "http://daniel.ponticelli.com/ns/dataExport";

tabla.Poll_Instance_id = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "Poll_Instance_id");
tabla.POLL_description = (string)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_description");
tabla.dt_start = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_start"));
tabla.dt_end = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_end"));
tabla.POLL_status = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_status");
tabla.dt_created = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_created"));
tabla.dt_updated = DateTime.Parse((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_updated"));
tabla.id_original_clone = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "id_original_clone");
tabla.target_locs = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "target_locs");
tabla.id_poll = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "id_poll");
```

This code now gives the exception on the third line! (the one that begins with `tabla.Poll_Instance_id`).  If I set a breakpoint on the "wrong" code just before the last line, I can check in VS that indeed the values are being retrieved from the XML and set on the object `tabla` as expected; so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: So you're saying that you change the last line and code several lines before that stops working? That doesn't make any sense, there must be something else going on.

Comment: The only way that could happen is if you use different XML on the same code that is missing values. It's won't just magically fail at random like you claim.

Comment: @svick You are right, that does not makes any sense.  The only thing that changes between tests is the last line, then the code breaks several lines before.

Comment: @JeffMercado It's not random: if you you add the namespace on the last line, it breaks 9 lines before; if you don't, then it breaks  right on that line.  To avoid interference, I am using the same XML on each test.

Comment: Well it's not going to break on that line either just because you changed a name on a later line.  If there was a problem on that line, it would have broken on that line for both cases.  But alas, it doesn't as you say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, thanks to @lazyberezovsky for pointing me to the right direction with the root() thing.

The problem was on the `Descendants()` method, which gives me all the descendant nodes; so I was getting the PollInstance node and also the `Poll_instance_id` and the others. That's why it breaks on the first line in the "right" code: after processing the first node, it choked on the others.

Instead I have to use the `Elements()` method which returns only the direct childs; in my case, only the `PollInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

Your date string has invalid format `a.m.` - use `am` without dots

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://daniel.ponticelli.com/ns/dataExport">
  <PollInstance>
    <Poll_Instance_id>1</Poll_Instance_id>
    <POLL_description>Mes 1</POLL_description>
    <dt_start>01/09/2012 12:00:00 am</dt_start>
    <dt_end>30/09/2012 12:00:00 am</dt_end>
    <POLL_status>0</POLL_status>
    <dt_created>03/09/2012 09:50:36 am</dt_created>
    <dt_updated>03/09/2012 09:50:36 am</dt_updated>
    <id_original_clone>0</id_original_clone>
    <target_locs>0</target_locs>
    <id_poll>1</id_poll>
  </PollInstance>
</root>
```

Also you should use namespace when getting `instancia` node, or you should start from Root `xdoc.Root.Descendants().First()`:

```
XNamespace ra = "http://daniel.ponticelli.com/ns/dataExport";
XElement instancia = xdoc.Descendants(ra + "PollInstance").First();

tabla.Poll_Instance_id = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "Poll_Instance_id");
tabla.POLL_description = (string)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_description");
tabla.dt_start = ParseDate((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_start"));
tabla.dt_end = ParseDate((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_end"));
tabla.POLL_status = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "POLL_status");
tabla.dt_created = ParseDate((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_created"));
tabla.dt_updated = ParseDate((string)instancia.Element(ra + "dt_updated"));
tabla.id_original_clone = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "id_original_clone");
tabla.target_locs = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "target_locs");
tabla.id_poll = (int)instancia.Element(ra + "id_poll");
```

And use ParseExact to parse date in your format

```
static DateTime ParseDate(string s)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

UPDATE if you can't change format of data of your xml, then simply do `String.Replace` to change `a.m.` to `am`:

```
static DateTime ParseDate(string s)
{
    string dateString = s.Replace("a.m.", "AM").Replace("p.m.", "PM");
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, 
          "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Instead of editing the XML to change all the `a.m.` to `am`, use the string `Replace(".", "")` method on the values after extracting them from the XML before converting them to a `DateTime.`

Comment: @ChuckSavage agree, this is also solution. Depends on who is creating those xml. If OP, then I think it's better to change format of data being written to xml. If he just reads, than yes, string replace will do the job

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The dates are being parsed Ok. Even commenting the lines that loads the dates, the problem is still there.  I'll give a try to what you say on the namespace and the root node.